# UIActivityViewController's "Assign To Contact" stopped working since iOS 8.0

Tags: ios8, uiactivityviewcontroller

I have the follwoing code working for iOS 7 app, where an image of my choice can be assigned to a contact's profile picture.

```
NSArray* actItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:image,string,nil];
UIActivityViewController *activityViewController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:actItems applicationActivities:nil];
activityViewController.excludedActivityTypes = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,UIActivityTypeAddToReadingList];
[activityViewController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
}];
[self presentViewController:activityViewController animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This works fine on iOS 7, but on iOS8, I cannot assign any image to any contact. Instead of being asked to crop the image within a circle, the app only shows the contact's detail without being able to assign the image to the person.

The app is granted access to contacts if I see Privacy section on Settings app. I'm aware that completion handler is deprecated on iOS 8, so I tried both with and without the statement for it. No change in result.

Your thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi,
Did you got any fix for that issue ? I am also facing the same issue in my application. But still i have't got any workaround/fix for that issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, not. Unless I'm mistaken, this is an iOS' bug. I reported it to bug report but so far no feedback. I'll post a fix when I find one. I'd appreciate if you'd do the same. Thanks!

Comment: @Yoshi : can you give me reported issue reference.